# Dependent Formula Information

Tags: formula, formula-field

For Example - I have a formula that calculates all of my sales by region on an object and then I have a parent object that sums all of my regions sales together. If I have a problem on the Parent table I have to look up it's formula and then see that it sums all of the children together - so I go to the child object and look at its formula. Is there a way to get to a list of the formula's that exist and see all of their dependent formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several free apps on the App Exchange that might come in handy for doing what you're asking about. There's [Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) by Surfing is fun, [Metadata Search](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI) by Satrang Technologies, [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) from Astrea, and [Handingo Studio](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009xMDNEA2) by Cloudingo.

I know that Metadata Search allows you to search for a specific field name and will return up to 400 instances of where it's used. I suspect that Schema Surfer however might be closer to what you're looking for but it might be worth trying one of the others as well to find out what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of to do this is to attempt to delete the field. That will tell you all of the places it is referenced in other formulas and code.  The problem here is that if it isn't referenced anywhere, you will delete the field. It can be recovered of course, but the API name will have changed slightly and you would probably want to change it back.